# Active Directory Migration Tool download come in a .dlm file, what is a .dlm?

Tags: admt

We are preparing to migrate a 2003 Windows Server to 2012 Windows Server.
We will need to migrate our active directory, and microsoft offers a free download for a Active Directory Migration Tool (ADMT 3.2) here ... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc974332(v=WS.10).aspx
But when I do this download I get a download.dlm file, what is this .dlm file?
My Windows 7 doesn't know what to do with it and I haven't been able to find online information about what to do with it?

Comment: To clarify: You're migrating to a new AD domain?

Answer (score 1):

That's the [Microsoft File Transfer Manger](http://transfers.one.microsoft.com/ftm/default.aspx?Target=install). You clicked on the "Download" button next to "selected file(s) using FTM". Instead, click the link labeled "download" to the right of the correct language.

[image]